# Rails - Uploading images with paperclip getting Errno::EEXIST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, uploading

Every time I try create a new article with an image attached I get this error:

> Errno::EEXIST in ArticlesController#create File exists @ sys_fail2 -
>   C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Temp/44a50f07b4bdc57740901280f9eddaf520170102-12672-1pnp3z2.PNG

Googling around did me no help. I found the file and saw that it only gets created while the local server is running, and I can't delete it manually.

It also says that it extracted it from my `articles_controller.rb` file:

> Extracted source (around line #23):

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

   if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
   else
    render 'new'
   end
end
```

If you need to see the rest of the files see here - [Rails getting error when trying to upload images with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410070/rails-getting-error-when-trying-to-upload-images-with-paperclip)
(the previous error was fixed)

Comment: It is saying that file already exists I will not recommend but Is it possible to completely delete the paperclip gem and re-install?  Look if anything is in public/system,  if it's empty, see if you can delete it and any other paperclip stuff then re-install and restart.  but first You can delete that in `rails console` manually and try again

Comment: @hjds were you able to solve this error, I am still getting this error and unable to find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this because I was using the latest paperclip version in my Gemfile (using the paperclip git url, hence using versio 5.1.0 at the time of this response). To solve this, I simply rolled back to a previous version 4.3.7 and I stopped getting the error. I've pin my app's paperclip to this version until I'm sure of a version of paperclip would allow me to upload.

Comment: I have  paperclip (5.1.0 82cd378)  but still getting the same error